# How to generate MathML equations in Excel and import into Word as proper equations?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

What I mean by the equation is a equation format you get when you go to insert->equation

[image]

If I copy MathML code to word, it works fine, so I tried concatenating MathML tags to strings, using `=CONCATENATE(...)` and then tried copying the table from excel

[image]

to word, to see if Word auto-formats the MathML code, but since I'm copying the whole table I guess Word doesn't recognize the equation.

At this point, I'm looking for a hacky way to do this, but I figured I ask here to see if someone have any ideas.

**Edit:**

The data in the text cells are formed by concatenation like this. Here is the formula for the 2 text cell shown in the example above.

```
=CONCATENATE(
    "<math xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML""> <mfrac> <mrow> <mi>",
    D2,
    "</mi><mo>&#xA0;</mo><mo>-</mo><mo>(</mo><mi>",
    B2,
    "</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><mrow><mi>",
    C2,
    "</mi><mo>-</mo><mo>(</mo><mi>",
    A2,
    "</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></mfrac></math>"
)
```

```
=CONCATENATE(
    "<math xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML""> <mfrac> <mrow> <mi>",
    D3,
    "</mi><mo>&#xA0;</mo><mo>-</mo><mo>(</mo><mi>",
    B3,
    "</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><mrow><mi>",
    C3,
    "</mi><mo>-</mo><mo>(</mo><mi>",
    A3,
    "</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></mfrac></math>"
)
```

**Edit 2**

Screenshot of all cells:

[image]

Comment: Please paste the data in the two cells shown above as text in your post.

Comment: @FlexYourData  I edited the question and added the data. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What data are in the cells A2:D3?

Comment: @FlexYourData just numbers

Comment: @FlexYourData I added a screen shot at the end of my post, just numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite interesting. If you paste MathML code `<math ... </math>` as *unformatted text* into Word, it will be formatted as an equation. However if it is formatted as html (copied from a website) or as an object (copied from an Excel cell), it will not. As an example, if you copy the below straight from superuser:

`<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"> <mfrac> <mrow> <mi>4</mi><mo>&#xA0;</mo><mo>-</mo><mo>(</mo><mi>2</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><mrow><mi>3</mi><mo>-</mo><mo>(</mo><mi>1</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></mfrac></math>`

And then paste straight into Word it will paste as HTML formatted junk:

[image]

However, it you click the paste drop-down (or hit CTRL), and select "Keep text only" (or use Paste Special), it will format correctly:

[image]

**TL;DR**

Excel requires unformatted text with a single `<math...> ... </math>` MathML element in order to recognise it and reformat it. Pasting multiple cells from Excel will not work, as in order to retain the table/cell formatting, Word has to paste the data with HTML formatting (or as an Excel object) and will not run the MATHML parser. Vice versa, if you paste as text only, the table formatting will be lost. Additionally, the parser only accepts one MathML element and will thus fail with multiple elements, pasting all as text only.

**Options for multiple equation pasting**

- Select all the MATHML cells in Excel, copy and paste them into Notepad. Now select them one by one, cut and paste them into Word.
- Generate each equation in excel without the <math ...>  and  tags.  Put the start tag in the very top row and the end tag at the bottom. Now join it all together using `=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE, B1:B10)`. Copy the result and paste as text only into Word. Edit the daisy-chained equation and press enter in between each to separate them into individual equations.
- As above, but figure out how Word does line breaks in MathML (I couldn't, mspace tag doesn't seem to work). Maybe try normal Office Open XML line break tags?
- If you really want to paste the equations inside a table, make a blank table inside a blank Word doc, pasting in one simple MathML equation, save and close. In explorer rename the Word .docx to .zip, unzip and search for the appropriate OOXML file. Edit it manually, and see it you can make sense of the OOXML tags in order to hack the equations into the OOXML. Replace, save, rezip, rename back to .docx and check!
- I see Word's built-in equation editor also supports {LaTeX} and /UnicodeMath formats. Perhaps look into those to enable you to code the table natively as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I ended up using VBA to generate the whole table in word. VBA allows you to convert a text to a `OMathEquation` and insert it into a cell in a table. Which turned out better than my initial thought of using excel, since ultimately I only needed the table in Word.

Comment: Ah thanks for the feedback. That is certainly another option, if another user is perhaps determined to use Excel, is to generate the OMath objects in VBA in Excel, then copy-and-paste the Excel table over to Word afterwards. Do you mind sharing your VBA code?